# Does XPath have a defined way to retrieve the URI of a namespace from its abbreviation when the URI is not known?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to write an XPath query to extract the URI of a specific namespace that will always use the same abbrevation.

Example:

```
<RequestPacket xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="urn:dont:really:care">
    <a:Requests xmlns:queryNS="urn:uri:i:need">
        <a:Request xsi:type="queryNS:GetImportantData">
            <queryNS:Version>3</queryNS:Version>
            ...
        </a:Request>
    </a:Requests>
</RequestPacket>
```

I need to extract the URI which corresponds to the `queryNS` namespace, which in my example would be `urn:uri:i:need`.

Is this possible? If so, could someone please help?

I tried to get it using the `namespace-uri()` function, but to do so, I have to specify a node, which I can only do by specifying the namespaces at each node (which is what I'm trying to figure out). So it seems like a chicken and egg situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<RequestPacket xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="urn:dont:really:care">
    <a:Requests xmlns:queryNS="urn:uri:i:need">
        <a:Request xsi:type="queryNS:GetImportantData">
            <queryNS:Version>3</queryNS:Version>
            ...
        </a:Request>
    </a:Requests>
</RequestPacket>';
```

--use `namespace-uri()` against a node, which is living *within* this namespace

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'namespace-uri((//*:Version)[1])',N'nvarchar(max)')
```

--This might be one of the rare situations, where [`FROM OPENXML` is still helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/openxml-sql-server#openxml-parameters). Try this:

```
DECLARE @docHandle INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xml;
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, '',1)   
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

The result

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | parentid | nodetype | localname     | prefix  | namespaceuri                              | datatype | prev | text                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 0  | NULL     | 1        | RequestPacket | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 0        | 2        | xsi           | xmlns   | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 10 | 2        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 3  | 0        | 2        | a             | xmlns   | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 11 | 3        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | urn:dont:really:care                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 4  | 0        | 1        | Requests      | a       | urn:dont:really:care                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 5  | 4        | 2        | queryNS       | xmlns   | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 12 | 5        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | urn:uri:i:need                            |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 6  | 4        | 1        | Request       | a       | urn:dont:really:care                      | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 7  | 6        | 2        | type          | xsi     | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 13 | 7        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | queryNS:GetImportantData                  |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 8  | 6        | 1        | Version       | queryNS | urn:uri:i:need                            | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                      |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 14 | 8        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | NULL | 3                                         |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 9  | 6        | 3        | #text         | NULL    | NULL                                      | NULL     | 8    | ...                                       |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

You can use the `parentid` and the `nodetype` to find your URI: The attribute `queryNS` has the id `5`. This is the parentid of element `12`, where the `#text` is the URI you are looking for. But this cannot be used within *adhoc / inline* queries.

### UPDATE: You might use `.query()`

```
SELECT @xml.query(
N'
<root>
{
    for $nd in //*
    return
    <nd ns="{namespace-uri($nd)}" name="{local-name($nd)}" value="{($nd/text())[1]}">
    {
        for $attr in $nd/@*
        return
        <attr ns="{namespace-uri($attr)}" name="{local-name($attr)}" value="{$attr}"  />
    }
    </nd>
}
</root>
');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <nd ns="" name="RequestPacket" value="" />
  <nd ns="urn:dont:really:care" name="Requests" value="" />
  <nd ns="urn:dont:really:care" name="Request" value="&#xA;            ...&#xA;        ">
    <attr ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="type" value="queryNS:GetImportantData" />
  </nd>
  <nd ns="urn:uri:i:need" name="Version" value="3" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I’ll try these out

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the namespace axis:

```
string(namespace::queryNS)
```

or if the namespace prefix is not known statically

```
string(namespace::*[name()=$prefix])
```

The namespace axis is not available in XQuery, and is deprecated in XPath 2.0+, so you can instead use

```
namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix, $element)
```

**CAVEAT**: I just noticed the question was tagged sql-server. I know nothing of the XPath/XQuery implementation in SQL Server other than the fact that it's not always conformant.